# Finding the derivative at a point given some values including the derivative of the inverse at the same point.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inverse-function

I was wondering how to continue with this problem:

The table below gives selected values for a differentiable and increasing function $f$ and its derivative. If $g$ is the
inverse function of $f$, what is the value of $g'(3)$?

$f(0) = 1,f(1) = 3,f(2) = 11$.

$f'(0) = 1, f'(1) = 5, f'(2) = 13.$

I realize that since $(1,3)$ is on the initial function $f$, $(3,1)$ is on the inverse. However, I am a little confused as to how to continue from there.

Comment: Do you know the formula for d/dx (g(x)) where g is the inverse of f. Geometrically the the intuition for the formula comes from the fact that g is the reflection of f accross the line y=x. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that, now I see how to proceed. Correct me if I'm wrong, but proceeding by $g'(3) = \frac{1}{f'(g(3))}$ and noting that $g(3) = 1$ does the trick, due to the reflection across the $y = x$ line.